# simple_html_dom for faster retrieval

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to do some web scraping using simple_html_dom. But I just want inner text of a span element only. Do I have to load the entire page for that? It is taking a lot of time since I am running it in a loop. What are other alternatives to do this faster?

Here is what I am doing now-

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('span') as $element) {
    if($element->innertext=="some text") {
        $html->clear();
        unset($html);
        break;
    }
    else {
        //do something
        }
```

This is too slow if this is used inside a loop. Faster way to do this?

Comment: Have you tested both given answers bellow? And if you did; could you provide us with the results in performance?

Answer (score 0):

You could give the following a try:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$content = $xpath->query("//span")->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $content;
```

Comment: close, but it doesn't address the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the speed, but instead of doing `foreach` loop, you can do something like this

`$html->find( $selector, $idx )`

```
<?php
  $html = file_get_html( $url );
  if ( is_object( $html ) ) {
    if ( $span = $html->find( "span", 0 ) ) {
      $span->innertext  = "some text";
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest will be:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$content = $xpath->query("//span[contains(text(), 'some text')]")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```